# How to show sub query columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this simple query

```
SELECT * from switch_person where PTPK = (
SELECT PK from projects where TeamLead  = 1 and status = 1)
```

It is showing me `swith_person` columns correctly. Additionally I want to display `projects` table column.
sub query table "`projects`" include a colum which I want to display as well with `switch_person` columns. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use join instead of subquery:

```
SELECT * 
from switch_person 
join project on PTPK = PK
where TeamLead  = 1 and status = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to select multiple columns, join to a derived table, instead of using a subquery, and then you can select multiple derived table columns:

```
SELECT x.PK, x.Col1, x.Col2, ...
from switch_person 
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT PK, Col1, Col2
   FROM projects 
   WHERE TeamLead  = 1 and status = 1
) x
ON PTPK = x.PK;
```